# How can I fix this 3-column layout?

Tags: css

I have a 3-column layout.

All columns are defined as divs. And they are all implementing the same css:

```
.div-column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

As long as the content of the columns is not too wide, they stay beside each other as expected. The last column however contains a div with some text. If this text gets too long, the whole column breaks out of line.

```
<div id=column3 class=div-column>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.    
    </div>
</div>
```

I expected the text to wrap if it does not fit in one line. What can I do to make sure the the length of that text does not matter? In other words: How can I make sure that the 3-column layout does not break?

Important: I MUST NOT work with fixed widths (width, min-width, max-width) for the columns!!!

Thanks so much for (hopefully simple) ideas!

Comment: how about max-width? that still allows the div to be smaller but when it reaches the specified with it doesn't grow bigger. max-width:250px;

Comment: @Marco: I just set up a simple test scenario. Your fix works great! But: I must not work with fixed widths (or max-width). I was hoping for a solution that would avoid this...

Comment: i build a jsfiddle for u, ill make an answer containing my solution.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks, but no worries any more. Nathan Lee just posted a perfect solution for me. THX!!!

Comment: thats the great thing about max-width you dont have to. you can work with content instead of widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want all the three `divs` to exist at the same place and not to scroll down. For that you have to add a `display:table-cell;` to the `div-column` class.
Here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fzfp5/1/).

**The HTML:**

```
<div id=column3 class=div-column>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.    
    </div>
</div>

<div class=div-column>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.    
    </div>
</div>

<div class=div-column>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.    
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.div-column {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;

}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Your second solution is perfect for my scenario. Thanks so much. YOu really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

how about max-width? that still allows the div to be smaller but when it reaches the specified with it doesn't grow bigger.

```
max-width:250px;
```

[The JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTVFA/)